# Retrieved database time validation

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on a class scheduling using PHP. What I want to happen is to notify the user if the schedule is already existing or if it overlaps the other schedules in the database.

For each schedule, I need to consider three things. The time, day and room.

Example:

**Existing on DB:** MWF 9:00am - 10:00am; Room A

---

**User Input #1:** MWF 9:00am - 10:00am; Room A

*Notification: Schedule Existing.*

**User Input #2:** MWF 8:00 - 10:00am; Room A

**User Input #3:** MWF 9:30 - 10:00am; Room A

*Notification: Schedule Overlap.*

Ideas please. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and dirty solution in pseudo-code

table rooms (Room_id [int], Room_name [varchar])
table room_use (Sunday [bit], Monday [bit], Tuesday [bit], Wednesday [bit], Thursday [bit], Friday [bit], Saturday [bit], Start_time [Time], End_time [Time])

```
Start transaction;
select count(*) as n from Room_use 
where Room_id=?  and  Time between ? and ?  and
#build this dynamically with php
(Sunday=1 or Monday=1 or Tuesday=1 or Wednesday=1 or Thursday=1 or Friday=1 or Saturday=1)

if n>0 rollback
else insert into room_use (Room_id, Sunday, Monday .......) values (?,?,?......)
commit;
```